# Record query while update record in table row in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have the following question:
In SSMS when I click on Edit Top 200 Rows in the Query Pane and I update one record directly in the result View Pane in the SQL Pane I have the Query for selecting the table, but can I record the query(snapshot of the query) when I edit a row in the table (the UPDATE query)?

I want to catch the SQL code for updating certain values in table rows, but don't know how to do it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSMS doesn't offer you a "script this action" in the Edit N Rows dialog like it does for many other types of dialogs. You can perform the action while capturing it in a variety of ways:

- [Extended Events](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/216771/1186) (best) - including [XEvents profiler](https://sqlperformance.com/2019/02/extended-events/capture-queries-sql-server)
- [server-side trace](https://sqland.wordpress.com/2017/12/08/what-is-server-side-trace-and-how-to-use-it/) (meh)
- SQL Profiler (not advisable in a production environment)